# How to solve this problem when it said TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not a coder and am so new in this field. I used Google App Script for my last project and it worked well before. However, when I tried to write another one for a new project, it said

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null
myFunction  @ Code.gs:4**

I am sure that I got the sheet name right. So after looking for solution on the internet, I tried using the code with another sheet with same format but it still did not work.

Here is my code;

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("IPP1");
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 4).getValue() ;
  var Subject = 'XX';
  var Bcc = "XX@gmail.com";
  
  //Create the message body
  var Name= sheet.getRange(LastRow, 2).getValue();
  var Message = 'XXX';
  MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, Subject, Message, {bcc:Bcc});
}
```

Comment: Set the breakpoint to line 4 and run the debugger in debug mode. Is Sheet defined or null? 
You may not have an IPP1 sheet.

Comment: Is there a blank after IPP1 as name of the sheet ?

Comment: You've defined the variable `Sheet` with a capital **S**, then you you've used twice a small **s** to refer to it: `var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange..` and also here: `var Name= sheet.getRange..`